# Find a language L with Rank(L)=k such that Rank($L^R$)>$2^{(k+1)}$

Tags: computer-science, automata, formal-languages, finite-automata

I'm having trouble to find a language L such that 
Rank(L)=k AND Rank($L^R$)>$2^{(k+1)}$.
(while $L^R$ is L reverse, and Rank is the number of states of the minimal DFA of L by the Myhill–Nerode theorem).

I've been thinking about a language such $L^R$={0}{0,1}$^{(k+1)}$ which has $2^{(k+2)}$ equivalence classes and than see how $L$ looks like, but I couldn't find one that gives me a Rank(L)=k.

is it possible that there is no such language?

Comment: What is the "rank" of a language? I am not familiar with that term.

Comment: For a language L- Rank(L) will be the amount of the equivalence classes of L

Comment: Which equivalence? If you mean the Nerode equivalence, the rank is better defined as the number of states of the minimal DFA of $L$.

Comment: Yes, I meant to the Nerode equivalence.